# JaCoCo Command Line Interface (CLI) Report generation leads to: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class $CLASS is already instrumented

Tags: java, junit, report, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm using JUnit to test my code and to access private methods/fields I use reflection which doesn't play well with JaCoCo on-the-fly instrumentation; Therefore, I started doing the off-line instrumentation.

I use the following command to perform the off-line instrumentation:

```
java.exe \
  -jar C:\jacoco\jacococli.jar \
  instrument \
  C:\project\main\main.jar \
  --dest C:\project\coverage
```

After that I end up with the instrumented JAR here:

- C:\project\coverage\main.jar

I then run my JUnit tests and on the classpath I provide:

```
C:\jacoco\jacocoagent.jar;C:\project\coverage\main.jar;...
```

This seems to work fine as I end up with the jacoco.exec file I expect.

When I try to generate a report for this jacoco.exec file using:

```
java.exe \
  -jar C:\jacoco\jacococli.jar \
  report \
  C:\project\coverage\jacoco.exec \
  --classfiles C:\project\coverage\main.jar \
  --html C:\project\coverage\report
```

I then receive this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing C:\project\coverage\main.jar@my/package/MyClass.class.
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:166)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:138)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:161)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:197)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeZip(Analyzer.java:269)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:200)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:230)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.ClassInfo.execute(ClassInfo.java:58)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.execute(Main.java:89)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.main(Main.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class my/package/MyClass is already instrumented.
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.assertNotInstrumented(InstrSupport.java:176)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.internal.analysis.ClassAnalyzer.visitField(ClassAnalyzer.java:85)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassVisitor.visitField(ClassVisitor.java:294)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassReader.readField(ClassReader.java:883)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:694)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:120)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:136)
        ... 8 more
```

Why, when I try to generate a report, do I get error messages about a class already being instrumented?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha! I just found that I should be using the non-instrumented JAR for generating the report i.e.

```
java.exe \
  -jar C:\jacoco\jacococli.jar \
  report \
  C:\project\coverage\jacoco.exec \
  --classfiles C:\project\main\main.jar \
  --html C:\project\coverage\report
```

*Notice: The main\main.jar instead of the coverage\main.jar*

I found this out by trying to run:

```
java.exe \
  -jar C:\jacoco\jacococli.jar \
  classinfo \
  C:\project\coverage\main.jar
```

Which was producing the same error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class my/package/MyClass is already instrumented.
```

I posted the bug here hoping to improve messaging:
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/700